# Spanning trees of Complete Bipartite Graph

Tags: linear-algebra, trees, bipartite-graphs

I'd like to find an explicit formula of the number of the spanning trees of complete bipartite graph, i.e.

$$k(K_{m,n})$$

How can I deal with it?

Any hint to proceed?

**note** Especially, the one exploiting the result of Temperley's fomrula would be my preference.

Comment: Check out "Spanning Trees of the Complete Bipartite Graph" at https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-46908-4_38.

Comment: The formula turns out to be $m^{n-1} n^{m-1}.$

Comment: @ReinerMartin especially I am looking for the approach of exploiting Temeperley's formula.

Comment: Then check out http://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~atcagc14/materialy/Lecture_2_Spanning_trees.pdf.

Comment: @ReinerMartin what does the function L() refer to with a domain of G in Temperley's formula?